# How to do Feature Hashing for a few selected Vocabulary in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to do feature hashing for a limited set of vocabulary.
For eg: top 1000 words in a set of documents

I know that CountVectorizer has a input parameter called vocabulary which only counts those few vocabulary. Is there a similar feature in Feature Vectorizer. If not how else can i do this?

any help will be very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use feature hasing for that? It sounds like the perfect use for CountVectorizer?

Comment: i want to take top 10000 words in a set of document to create feature vector. But 10000 words will make the complexity high. So i want to take top 10000 words and hash those values to 1000 features to reduce complexity

Comment: In all honesty, it sounds like a really bad idea. Have you considered using feature selection instead to drop it from 10000 to 1000? or maybe PCA?

Comment: Thanks i will try that